# How can I combine 2 SQL queries on the same column in the same table?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to combine 2 queries into one. Both query the same table and same column name. I need the results in one query so that I can repeat region the results. I have tried UNION but this doesn't run the second half correctly. Query 1 is as follows:

```
   SELECT o.value AS sdate
    FROM order_option o
        INNER JOIN order_product p ON o.order_product_id = p.order_product_id 
    WHERE 
        p.product_id = '$_GET[u]'
        AND o.name = 'Start Date'
```

And query 2 is as follows...

```
SELECT o2.value AS sday
    FROM order_option o2
        INNER JOIN order_product p ON o2.order_product_id = p.order_product_id 
    WHERE 
        p.product_id = '$_GET[u]'
        AND o2.name = 'Number of Days'
```

Comment: Something tells me your database isn't normalized.

Comment: Please consider registering an account so you can edit your questions and leave comments.

Answer (score 1):

UNION should be correct.  Does the second query run correctly as shown?  if so, it should run the same way in a UNION.  You may try UNION ALL and see if that 'corrects' the query.

Comment: I have tried both, but the second query will not run correctly, as when I list the results of the first part in a repeat region (for example $query['sdate']) it lists the responses to both parts of the query, but i need the separate eg $query['sdate'] and $query['sday'] thanks!

Comment: still not sure what you are saying...  when you create a UNION the column name will be the name of the first column even though the values will be coming from all the queries...  so even sday values will come under the sdate column alias...

Comment: you can add a field to your result set that indicates which query it came from:

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of MAX and CASE like this

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Start Date' THEN o.value END) AS sdate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Number of Days' THEN o.value END) AS sday
FROM order_option o
    INNER JOIN order_product p USING (order_product_id)
WHERE 
    p.product_id = '$_GET[u]'
;
```